# Where is the eclipse project saved in Windows for Android?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, file, project

I've got a Windows set up compiling correctly and running well on my Android device.  Where is the project stored?  In the workspace folder I see only a meta data folder.  I see no options among the project explorer for opening the project in the desktop.  And the meta data folder is only 3 MB while my project folder is 80 MB.

I'm really confused.  Where is it?

Thanks!!

Comment: is should be there in the workplace you specified..

Comment: Right click your project --> Properties --> Resourse tab There you will get location of your project stored..

Comment: copy the project name from your eclipse the again import and checked the option of copy to save in hard disk

Answer (score 1):

RightClickon Project --> Select Properties
---> Select Resource

[image]

You can locate see ur Project Location

Comment: thanks!  That found it!  I was gonna say!  Damn, was it some hidden system...  haha.

Answer (score 0):

right click on `project->properties->Resources` in that you can see the location of your saved project.

Comment: I think question asked was `where is my project saved...` Didn't you read that....